# How to get rows from a table if total rows are more than 10 in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

I want to write a Oracle based query where I can choose if I want to see the results. Let's say:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
//when there are more than 10 rows
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What RDBMS and please explain better.

Comment: Choose... Choose the form of the destructor!

Comment: 10 rows in total, or 10 rows of a given condition?

Comment: Did you try something like: SELECT * FROM table WHERE count(some_column) > 10

Comment: @AllisonC - Can't have aggregates in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: select * from table where 10<(select count(*) from table)... Is this ok?

Comment: my answer offer one scan or none + maximum 10 rows :)

Answer (score 15):

```
select * from table
where 10 < (select count(*) from table)
```

Comment: That is what I also said, but is this ok? I know it works but is this sql code fine?

Comment: @Martin oracle sql.. How do I have to do this then?

Comment: @user999379 - Not sure what I was thinking there about avoiding 2 scans. If there is a way of doing it it escapes me at the moment. You could also use `COUNT(*) OVER()` but probably no advantage over this approach.

Answer (score 8):

Best speed:

```
select * from table
where 10=(select count(*) from
          table
          where rownum <11)
```

:)

---

**UPDATE**: Because there are suspicions that I claim something that is not true, here some tests:
In SQL Developer(keep in mind that select * from table will offer only first 50 rows, but count(*) read all requested rows)
The table has no indexes.

```
select
count(*) from
table
```

22074412 rows

3.16 seconds

---

```
select * from table where 10 = 
(select
count(*) from
table
where rownum <11
)
```

0.051 seconds

---

```
select * from table where 10 < 
(select
count(*) from
table
)
```

3.39 seconds

---

```
select count(*) from table where 10 < 
(select
count(*) from
table
)
```

7.69 seconds

---

```
select count(*) from table where 10 = 
(select
count(*) from
table
where rownum <11
)
```

3.42 seconds

**Cause**: Subquery with rownum is faster (it reads not the entire table)

Comment: Would this be even faster than LIMIT? If yes, How?

Comment: there is no LIMIT in oracle :) Rownum is somehow equivalent :)

Comment: It will not produce better speed then the rest of the count(*) queries

Comment: I think the otherwise. Let be a table with 10M rows. The subquery is evaluated first. My subquery run at speed light. It reads only 10 rows. The others will read the entire table -> slow. After that things run in the same mode. My **subquery** is faster.

Comment: Took me a little while to work out why this would be faster. @DanielHaviv This will be quicker. With a condition on ROWNUM, it then uses the STOPKEY execution plan step so doesn't need to do a full table/index scan.

Comment: I disagree and will prove it if asked to :)

Comment: hehe, prove it :) I've tested that. You are on Oracle?

Comment: @FlorinGhita *there is no LIMIT in oracle :) Rownum is somehow equivalent* Yes there is, **Top-n** row limiting feature introduced in 12c.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - before you go around telling people they are wrong, check the dates. Florin's answer was correct as of 2011, when he wrote his answer. If you want to alert readers that Oracle added a new feature, that's fine (and helpful), but don't open with "Yes there is".

Comment: @mathguy I never said anyone is wrong. "Yes there is", is followed by some context and information. I said from 12c onwards Oracle has introduced the new feature. I didn't post a new answer, rather commented on the answer which is absolutley fine. Anyway, appreciate your concern.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Var int;
SET @Var = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [somewhere]

IF @Var > 10
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [somewhere]
END
```

You mean something like that?
Or just how to use the where clause?

```
SELECT * 
FROM [somewhere]
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [somewhere]) > 10
```

Comment: This has the same "issue" as what Martin said, You're scanning the table twice...

Comment: @user999379 There aren't necessarily two table scans though. The count(*) can probably be done with an index scan which may be considerably faster than a table scan.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [table]) > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from YourTable where (select count(*) from YourTable ) > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to avoid double scans and you have valid statistics you can

```
select * from table a, all_tables b
where    b.num_rows > 10
and      b.table_name = 'table';
```

Comment: I'd probably use user_tables rather than all_tables. Or use all_tables along with a condition on the OWNER column.

Comment: However, there is no way I would put this into production code since it relies very heavily on up-to-date statistics. Not so bad on a large table with 10M rows but a bit dodgy on a table with only a few rows.